# Hales's fan associated with a polyhedron

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, convex-polytopes

In Hales's book (cited below), he associates what he calls a *fan* with any convex polyhedron in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
I will not define his notion of fan, but let his figure (p.137) serve as a definition:

   [image: HalesFan]
My question is: Has this natural object been defined and used previously in other
contexts and perhaps under another name?

---

> Thomas Hales, *Dense Sphere Packings: A Blueprint for Formal Proofs*. 2012.
> ([Cambridge link](http://www.cambridge.org/ar/academic/subjects/mathematics/geometry-and-topology/dense-sphere-packings-blueprint-formal-proofs))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fan Hales is using is called the "face fan" of the polytope.

In toric varieties, one mainly considers the outer normal fan of a polytope, which has a ray for each facet (perpendicular to it).  The face fan, on the other hand, has a ray for each vertex.  There is an inclusion-reversing map between the poset of faces of these two fans (if we omit the zero-faces).  So that is probably what Hales means by saying that the two notions bear some resemblance but are not the same.

Comment: Thank you, Hugh! This likely explains his comments about the notation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, fans have long been used in the theory of toric varieties. I believe they may have been introduced (as "éventails") by [Demazure (1970)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=284446). I don't know who first spelled out the relation with convex polyhedra, but that can be found in such books as [Oda (1988)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=922894) or [Audin (2004)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2091310).

I'm assuming this is the same notion you're after. In Audin's words, "The idea one must have in mind is that a fan is what is left from a convex polyhedron when the "sizes" of its faces are forgotten."

Comment: No doubt this is the reason he calls it a "fan." Hales does say, "a fan in our sense bears some relation to a toric variety fan." But he also says they are not the same. I'll have to puzzle this through. Thanks!